# I am looking for a way to turn intervals into absolute timepoints?

Tags: r

I have list of intervals between events but I need to turn them into a list of timepoints of the same events. Is there a way of adding up values continuously from one column to the other ? Results should like a little something like the table below. Right now only column Interval exists.

| Interval | Timepoint |
| --- | --- |
| 0.55 | 0.55 |
| 0.87 | 1.42 |
| 0.80 | 2.23 |
| 0.75 | 2.98 |
| 0.73 | 3.72 |
| 0.64 | 4.37 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cumsum()` function does exactly this!

```
df = data.frame( interval = interval, time = cumsum(interval) )
```